# Prevent injection in queries with execute

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sql-injection

I'm developing a reporting web with Visual Studio 2017. All my MYSQL queries are parameterized and works properly. The problem is in some queries that have EXECUTE command.

For example:

Instead of

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id=@id
```

I've put

```
set @sentencia='SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id=@id'
PREPARE stmt FROM @sentencia;
EXECUTE stmt using @id;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The execute case doesn't break but doesn't work because return no data.

I've tried this:

```
set @sentencia='SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id=?'
PREPARE stmt FROM @sentencia;
EXECUTE stmt using @id;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

But It doesn't work. The error message is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '16;
>         DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt' at line 1

16 corresponds to the value I've given to the parameter @id in my code.

```
       Dim myConnectionMYSQL As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
        myConnectionMYSQL.ConnectionString = CadenaDeConexion()
        myConnectionMYSQL.Open()
        Dim myCommandMYSQL As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(_Sentencia, myConnectionMYSQL)
        myCommandMYSQL.CommandTimeout = 9000
        myCommandMYSQL.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 100)
        myCommandMYSQL.Parameters("@id").Value = 16
        Dim daMYSQL As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(myCommandMYSQL)
        Dim dtMYSql As New DataTable
        daMYSQL.Fill(dtMYSql)
```

Anyone knows a possible solution?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where do you set @id ?

Comment: Did you forget a ";" at the end of the set?

Comment: Sorry I forget  write it. In my code has the ; jeje

Comment: I set the @id in my .net code. I've changed above

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot...

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id=?';     
SET @id= 'YOURID';
EXECUTE stmt USING @id;     
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

In your example you are ***not*** setting the `id`. It should have been...

```
 SET @id = 'SOMEID';
```

Comment: But my query is dynamic. Depends on the filter that the user choose, the @id is different. If I just replace the text in SET @id= [MYID];, I don't know if it would prevent SQL injection.